# Plotting World Bank data: the condition has length > 1

Tags: r, google-visualization, panel-data

I'm trying to plot some World Bank data using the googleVis package for R but it gives me the following error:

```
In if (class(x[[.x]]) == "Date") as.character(x[[.x]]) else x[[.x]] :
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

I've used the following code:

```
# load the packages
library(WDI) # package for importing World Bank data
library(plm) # package for working with panel data
library(googleVis) # the googleVis package

# import the data using the WDI package
LONG <- WDI(country=c("AGO","BEN","BWA","BFA","BDI"), indicator=c("SP.DYN.CBRT.IN",
"SP.DYN.TFRT.IN", "SP.POP.TOTL", "NY.GDP.PCAP.KN"), start=2005, end=2009, 
extra=FALSE)

# transform to panel format and encode the year variable as numeric
PANEL <- pdata.frame(LONG, c("country","year"))
PANEL$year <- as.numeric(as.character(PANEL$year))

# plot in a MotionChart using googleVis
MC <- gvisMotionChart(PANEL, idvar="country", timevar="year")
plot(MC)
```

Does anybody know why this is?

Comment: no errors on mint 12 with R 15.0

Comment: Alright, it must something else then. Thanks for taking the time to check! 

Btw, I've also got R 2.15 and the lastest googleVis.

Answer (score 0):

You do need to transform your data from ordinary data frame to panel data frame. You can directly call 'gvisMotionChart` with data frame argument.

Please see the code below:

```
library(WDI) # package for importing World Bank data
library(plm) # package for working with panel data
library(googleVis) # the googleVis package

# import the data using the WDI package
LONG <- WDI(
   country=c("AGO","BEN","BWA","BFA","BDI"), 
   indicator=c("SP.DYN.CBRT.IN", "SP.DYN.TFRT.IN", "SP.POP.TOTL", "NY.GDP.PCAP.KN"), 
   start=2005, 
   end=2009, 
   extra=FALSE)

# plot in a MotionChart using googleVis
MC <- gvisMotionChart(LONG, idvar="country", timevar="year")
plot(MC)
```

Output:
[image]